# get and create new named versions of Google Spreadsheets in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to find how to get named versions and create new named versions of Google Spreadsheet files in a Google Apps Script project.

I checked https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list but it doesn't seem to return the named version name. Nor do I see a method to create a new named version.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. But I think that the possibility which is implemented by the future update cannot be denied.

Comment: Very unfortunate. Thank you!