# How do I name the current version of a Google spreadsheet, document or presentation using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to give the current version of a Google spreadsheet a name using Google Apps Script. In the GUI I would do `File -> Version history -> Name current version` but since I need to do this to multiple files, I want to achieve this using a script.

I've found the [revisions reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions#resource) but that's not helping much.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146844/get-and-create-new-named-versions-of-google-spreadsheets-in-google-apps-scripts) question touches on a similar topic, but I've found the revisions.items.splice(-1) doesn't always list the `current` version but rather the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible to do at this moment. I've found a similar [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115421149). You can click on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the request and to receive updates.

It's not exactly the same but since it's asking for API support, "update the revisions" would presumably be supported too.